# How can I show/hide FreeMaker template FTL

Tags: freemarker

I'm new to [FreeMaker Template](http://freemarker.org/), In the below example, I want to show the `<@greet person="${name}"!/>` macro for 10 seconds only, then need to remove it, any idea how can I make it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <title>${title} | Kweet</title>
</head>
<body>

<@greet person="${name}"!/>


<#include "/copyright_footer.html">
</body>
</html>

<#macro greet person color="black">
  <font size="+2" color="${color}">Hello ${person}!</font>
</#macro>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with JavaScript (which you put into the template). It has nothing to do FreeMarker, as that only generates the page *before* it's sent to the browser.